# How to store session data using OAuth and doorkeeper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, oauth, doorkeeper

Is there uniform way of storing user settings that would be bound to particular OAuth token using doorkeeper gem (or OAuth in general)?

I'd like user to choose locale when logging in, that would be kept as long as the same token is used. In my use case I want settings to be session-specific instead user-specific -- multiple tokens can be issued to single resource owner, and have different settings.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a Preference model that would have an `oauth_token` and a `user_id` field. When your User sets a preference, a Preference is created, using the oauth_token and user_id along with whatever data is involved in their preference, in this case you'd have three fields in your Preferences table:

`oauth_token:string`, `user_id:integer` and `locale:string`

When a user logs on, the current_user.token can be used to match with the oauth field in your Preferences and then you can load the preferences.